# How to optimize aggregation pipeline in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I have a complex aggregation pipeline,but it works perfect when there is less data in collection like 300,400 but incase of huge amount of data like 20000,30000 it takes longer time to fetch and generate a pdf ,that pdf includes all the 30000 data ,so how to fast the process . Only by indexing or isthere any other way to achieve this?Please help......

Below I have provided service.ts file,

```
    async getQCResultSLcmExcel(
    filters: GetAllQcInspectionWithFilterSlcmDto,
    businessUnitId: string,
  ) {
    let startDateQuery = {};
    let endDateQuery = {};
    let commoditySearchQuery = {};
    let variantSearchQuery = {};
    const statusQuery = {};
    let cidNumberSearchQuery = {};
    const businessUnitFilterQuery = {};
    let generalSearchQuery = {};

    if (filters.startDate) {
      startDateQuery = {
        $expr: {
          $gte: [
            '$createdAt',
            {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: filters.startDate,
                timezone: '+05:30',
                format: '%m-%d-%Y',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    }

    if (filters.endDate) {
      endDateQuery = {
        $expr: {
          $lt: [
            '$createdAt',
            {
              $dateAdd: {
                startDate: {
                  $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: filters.endDate,
                    timezone: '+05:30',
                    format: '%m-%d-%Y',
                  },
                },
                unit: 'day',
                amount: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    }

    if (filters.searchByCommodity) {
      commoditySearchQuery = {
        'commodityData.name': {
          $regex: `${filters.searchByCommodity}`,
          $options: 'i',
        },
      };
    }
    if (filters.searchByVariant) {
      variantSearchQuery = {
        'commodityVariantData.name': {
          $regex: `${filters.searchByVariant}`,
          $options: 'i',
        },
      };
    }

    if (filters.searchByStatus) {
      statusQuery['status'] = filters.searchByStatus;
    }

    if (filters.searchByCIDNumber) {
      cidNumberSearchQuery = {
        $or: [
          {
            'commodityDetail.CIDNumber': {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByCIDNumber}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
          {
            'businessUnitData.name': {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByCIDNumber}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
          {
            'commodityDetail.LOTNumber': {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByCIDNumber}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
        ],
      };
    }
    if (filters.searchByGeneralSearch) {
      generalSearchQuery = {
        $or: [
          {
            qcId: {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByGeneralSearch}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
          {
            'businessUnitData.name': {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByGeneralSearch}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
          {
            'userData.name': {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByGeneralSearch}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
        ],
      };
    }

    if (businessUnitId) {
      businessUnitFilterQuery['businessUnitId'] = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(
        businessUnitId,
      );
    }

    const result = await this.qcInspectionModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            startDateQuery,
            endDateQuery,
            statusQuery,
            businessUnitFilterQuery,
            { isDeleted: false },
            { isSLCMQcInspection: true },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'mastercommodities',
          localField: 'commodityId',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                name: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'commodityData',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$commodityData',
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'commodityvariants',
          localField: 'commodityVariantId',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                name: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'commodityVariantData',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$commodityVariantData',
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'businessunits',
          localField: 'businessUnitId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'businessUnitData',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                name: 1,
                businessUnitCode: 1,
                _id: 0,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$businessUnitData',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'createdBy',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'userData',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                firstName: 1,
                lastName: 1,
                _id: 0,
                name: { $concat: ['$firstName', ' ', '$lastName'] },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$userData',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            commoditySearchQuery,
            variantSearchQuery,
            generalSearchQuery,
            cidNumberSearchQuery,
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          createdAt:
            filters.sortOrder && filters.sortOrder != SortOrder.Ascending
              ? SortOrder.Descending
              : SortOrder.Ascending,
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          'QC ID': {
            $cond: {
              if: '$qcId',
              then: '$qcId',
              else: '',
            },
          },
          'CID Number': {
            $cond: {
              if: '$commodityDetail',
              then: '$commodityDetail.CIDNumber',
              else: '',
            },
          },
          Commodity: {
            $cond: {
              if: '$commodityData',
              then: '$commodityData.name',
              else: '',
            },
          },
          Date: {
            $cond: {
              if: '$createdAt',
              then: {
                $dateToString: { format: '%d-%m-%Y', date: '$createdAt' },
              },
              else: '',
            },
          },
          'Analyst Name': {
            $cond: {
              if: '$userData',
              then: '$userData.name',
              else: '',
            },
          },
          'Business Unit': {
            $cond: {
              if: '$businessUnitData',
              then: '$businessUnitData.name',
              else: '',
            },
          },
          'LOT No': {
            $cond: {
              if: '$commodityDetail',
              then: '$commodityDetail.LOTNumber',
              else: '',
            },
          },
          Location: {
            $cond: {
              if: '$location',
              then: '$location.name',
              else: '',
            },
          },
          'Middleware Status': {
            $cond: {
              if: '$middlewareStatus',
              then: '$middlewareStatus',
              else: '',
            },
          },
          Status: {
            $cond: {
              if: '$status',
              then: '$status',
              else: '',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);

    if (result && result.length > 0) {
      const payload = await generateExcel(result, 'slcm-qc-reports');
      const excelData = await this.uploadService.fileUpload(payload);
      return excelData.Location || '';
    } else {
      return ERROR_MESSAGE.NO_DATA_EXPORT;
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are always slow, do you really need them?

You can make the Date filter more efficient by using an 3rd party date library, e.g. [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/)

I would do it like this:

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon"); 

if (filters.startDate) {
   startDateQuery = { createdAt: { $gte: DateTime.fromFormat(filters.startDate, "MM-dd-yyyy").setZone("+05:30").toJSDate() } }
}    
if (filters.endDate) {
   endDateQuery = { createdAt: { $lt: DateTime.fromFormat(filters.startDate, "MM-dd-yyyy").plus({ days: 1 }).setZone("+05:30").toJSDate() } }
}
```

It looks a bit strange to use time zones when your input data has no time information at all. Note, libraries like Luxon provide methods like `startOf('day')`, they are also aware of time zones.

I assume most of the `$lookup` return only one document. In this case, you don't need to `$unwind`. Projections like

```
{ $set: { commodityVariantData: { $first: "$commodityVariantData" } } }
```

might be faster.

The `$match` operator also works on arrays, perhaps you can even skip `$unwind/$set`. Put the conditions as early as possible, they can be also part of the `$lookup`.

Apart from that, four `$lookup` is rather much, you may review your data model. NoSQL databases like MongoDB are not optimized for joins. Consider embedded documents.